# Can you run two motors of different hp off the same VFD independently?

Tags: power, motor, vfd, fluid-pump

Can you use the same VFD to run two motors of different hp (20 hp and 10 hp) if all other parameters are the same? The motors will never run at the same time, it will be one or the other, and the speed will be constant and not change throughout the use.

Can this be done without having to change the VFD parameters? The VFD will be rated for the biggest motor (20 hp).

Comment: What particular VFD parameters are you considering that are not related to the motor to be run?

Comment: FLA of each motor. based on which motor is selected to be run by the vfd, does that settings in the vfd require to be changed

Answer (score 2):

Not really. The VFD is relying on the measurement of the current (magnitude and phase) that the motor pulls. If you have two motors, it gets nasty.

Having said that, [Rockwell says](https://www.rockwellautomation.com/en-us/company/news/blogs/controlling-multiple-motors-with-one-vfd.html):

"A variable frequency drive (VFD) can be used to control multiple motors in some applications provided the right design considerations are made and appropriate protection is provided for each motor.

This offers several advantages such as lower cost, reduction in panel space and reduced control complexity.

If the application falls within these specific conditions – and each motor can operate at the same speed and can accommodate a VFD as a single point of failure – the next step is to review design considerations and to select the right components. The VFD must be sized properly, and each motor needs protection. "

Answer (score 1):

Some drives can select 2 or even 4 sets of parameters for differents motors (rated power, current and speed, inductance, resistance, overload limits, thermal models and others). You can select which motor parameters is active by digitals inputs or communication bits, and at the same time, switch by contactors which motor is feeded from the VFD. These changes must be done with the drive stopped. This way, a VFD could supply non simultaneous motors with similar rated power, for example horizontal and vertical axis of a machine.
Normally this configuration is used with open loop speed control, because in case of using speed feed back should be also switched with motor selection. This should be also applicable to independent cooling fans, brakes, or temperature sensors of the differents motors.